# WooCommerce change product title?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a site where I need to change the product title to remove the word'`-product' from the product title when it is shown.

For example the product name is stored as "1000 Piece Puzzle -Product" when the shopper comes to the front page we want them to see "1000 Piece Puzzle" (without the "-product")

I tried

```
remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title',10);
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','fun',10);
function fun($ttl)
{
   echo str_replace('-product', '', $ttl);;
}
```

However it would not work. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that by adding a filter to change the product title. Instead of using an action.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_product_title', 10, 2 );
function change_product_title( $title, $id ) {
    $Find = '-product';
    $ReplaceWith = '';

    //REMOVE DESIRED STRING FROM PRODUCT TITLE
    $title = str_replace($Find, $ReplaceWith, $title);

    return $title;
}
```